# how to find what address a char pointer is pointing to?

Tags: c++, c

I have an array of char pointers and I want to know the address these pointer are pointing too. Essentially I want to know the address of the string the char pointer points to.
[image]

I want to know How to get access to `0x555555769280` for example
I can see it in the debugger, but I want to be able to print the address.

Comment: `printf("%p\n", ptr2[0]);`?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of "How to get address of a pointer in c/c++?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to print a pointer, the value stored will be printed instead of address because `std::cout` will treat `char *` as a null-terminated string and print the string. To get the address, you can cast it to a pointer. Try this:

```
cout<< (void *) ptr2[0];
```

Comment: so `(void *)` will make a `char *` a plain pointer which forces std to print the address it points to and that's it?

Comment: Yes.. that's it.

Comment: does this work with reference ? 

int a = 5;
cout<< (void *) &a;

Comment: Yes, it should.